# PHP validation without refreshing

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli, phpmyadmin, page-refresh

I'm the initial programmer. I have been learning PHP for a short time, currently I am writing a social-media application for people who love books. For a few days, the user registration is a problem, form is placed in the "modal" and added there using JS, the problem is that after sending the form the page is refreshed, so I would like to ask if it is possible to code script that it would return the verification result without refreshing, and after the correct sending of data to the database, information about the registration appeared.

This is link to code of all files : https://hastebin.com/pudisakowi.xml

Sorry if it's dumb question, but i cannot get it how to pass this problem.

I've tried with code like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
const regiterUrl = "link to the register_page.php";

$("#registerForm").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = $(this).serialize();
    $("#login-text").fadeIn();
    $("#div-form").hide();
    $("#btn-register").attr("disabled", true);
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: regiterUrl,
        data: $("#registerForm").serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log(response);
                $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('hide')
            }, 2000);
        },
        error: function(response) {
            alert("WYSTĄPIŁ BŁĄD");
        }
    });
});
```

});
but it gives always succes and nothing is saved to the database.

I will be grateful for the directions of what to do, or to indicate what is wrong in the current code.

Comment: If this AJAX is always returning a success then the issue is with your PHP and not the AJAX.

Comment: Please show us your PHP code (of course hiding any sensitive information).

Comment: `$statement = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (login,password,reminderKey,reminderKeyText) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"); ` ? There's too much code, this is the only thing I could find

Comment: newplayer65, there's link to all files including php https://hastebin.com/pudisakowi.xml

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick look on it and i think the refreshing problem is because type="submit"

```
<button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" name="register">Zarejestruj</button>
```

You can do it this way:

```
<button class="btn btn-info register_btn"  name="register">Zarejestruj</button>
```

And than:

```
$(".register_btn").on("click", function(event)...
```

Besides you don't need a form tag for the whole stuff, so you can delete the form tag line and if you want to pass the data to ajax, it is better to write it like 
data: {param1:value, param2:value} 
instead auf the whole registration formular...

I didn't test that, but hope it helps you.

cheers

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it deleting "type="submit" didn't help (modal is still closing because of reload). "and if you want to pass the data to ajax, it is better to write it like data: {param1:value, param2:value} instead auf the whole registration formular" could u show me example of using this because i don't get it :(

Comment: did you delete the form tag? you can write the data like that. 1) var varid = $("#xampleid").val(); and than you can pass them like data:{id: varid} and so on.. here at the end of the page is the data explanation. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

JQuery AJAX error callback gets invoked in case there is any error while making the request. Success callback gets fired once you receive a legitimate response from the server.

In this case, you should rewrite the server side script in order to support AJAX calls. And you will have to alter the client side code a bit. Please refer below code samples.

- Server Side Code

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
    $response['success'] = false;

    //Set content type here, So the browser will be able to parse your response properly.
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    //Data validation
    if ($any_error) {

        $response['errors'][] = 'Error Message';

    } elseif ($another_error ) {

        $response['errors'][] = 'Another Error Message';

    } else {

        //Your Form processing code
        //You may create a flag($form_processing) to verify success/failure
        if ($form_processing ) {
            $response['success'] = true;
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}
```

- Client Side Code

  ```
  $(document).ready(function () {

      const regiterUrl = "link to the register_page.php";

      $("#registerForm").on("submit", function (event) {

          event.preventDefault();
          const formData = $(this).serialize();
          $("#login-text").fadeIn();
          $("#div-form").hide();
          $("#btn-register").attr("disabled", true);

          $.ajax({
              type: "post",
              url: regiterUrl,
              data: $("#registerForm").serialize(),
              datatype : "application/json",
              success: function (response) {

                  if( response.success == true ) {
                      //Success
                      $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('hide')
                  } else {
                      var errors = response.errors;
                      //Code for display errors
                  }

              },
              error: function (response) {
                  alert("WYSTĄPIŁ BŁĄD");
              }
          })
      })
  });
  ```